# Are these two logical statements equal?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I found this question from a website:

> "Neither the fox nor the lynx can catch the hare if the hare is alert and quick."
>
> Let:
>
> P: The fox can catch the hare
>
> Q: The lynx can catch the hare.
>
> R: The hare is alert
>
> S: The hare is quick

If I write these statements in logic this way:

$(\lnot P \land \lnot Q) \implies (R  \land S)$

And this statement:

$(R \land S) \implies (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$

Since logically $p \implies q$ and $q \implies p$ are equal, **is it correct to translate the sentence without taking care of order of the same operation** (e.g., $\implies$)?

**Are the two translations correct for the sentence?**

Comment: But $p \to q$ and $q \to p$ are not logically equivalent.

Comment: @pjs36 So where did I go wrong here?

Comment: @direprobs Consider the two natural language statements: "I'll go to the beach, if it's sunny" and "If it's sunny, I'll go to beach". How do you model (i.e. "write in logic") each of them? After answering this, it will be easy to tell you where you went wrong. And maybe you'll even see it for yourself.

Comment: I don't get the down vote to the question. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: @GitGud Let's say: _P_:I'll got to the beach; _Q_: It's sunny. So "I'll go to the beach, if it's sunny" in logic is: $P \rightarrow Q$ this means (If) I'll go to the beach (then) it's sunny. Taking the other one,  "If it's sunny, I'll go to beach". $Q \rightarrow P$, if it's sunny, I'll go to the beach. Same meaning, but different order, does the order matter here?

Comment: Some sentences for example have the action before the condition, like: "I eat apples if I'm hungry", then in logic should I make _P:_ I'm hungry because it's the condition and _Q:_ I eat apples? Then this will be $P \rightarrow Q$?

Comment: Okay let me make this clear, "Neither the fox nor the lynx can catch the hare **(if the hare is alert and quick).**" should I change the order of the sentence to the following: "**(if the hare is alert and quick)**, neither the fox nor the lynx can catch the hare" and then translate it to logic?

Comment: @direprobs That's it. The symbol "\to" is used to model conditional statements: "Conditional statement: an “if p, then q” compound statement (ex. If I throw this ball into the air, it will come down); p is called the antecedent, and q is the consequent." ([Source](https://web.stanford.edu/~bobonich/dictionary/dictionary.html)). You can't change the order, it does alter the meaning. Perhaps the following example makes it clearer. "If it's raining, then I get wet". Surely you can get wet from other ways other than rain, which makes "If I get wet, then it's raining" false.

Comment: If you got this, you might want to update the question somehow.

Comment: @GitGud So the correct order for the above example in the original question is: $(R \land S) \rightarrow (\lnot P \land \lnot Q)$ ? The same as the original order.

Comment: @direprobs You are correct.

Comment: @GitGud I think proper latex etiquette is to use \implies rather than \to, which matches \iff, and conceivably would allow a user to distinguish between the two locally with font choice.

Comment: @DanielV But what's at stake here clearly is the [material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional). Using $\implies$ is meaning something else.